# How to have Google show the number of results in book search

Tags: google-search

Searching on Google (All) gives the number of results:

[image]

Searching on Google Books does not:

[image]

Is there a way to have Google show the number of results in Books search?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It automatically takes you into **Tools**

Click on the **Tools** button to toggle (hide) the layover.

[image: result]